# I dont really understand this "move_uploaded_file" error

Tags: php, database, image, forms

i think my problem is in my

**$dossier = "/AprimeWeb/img/";**

I try many things for my $dossier ($folder in english)

With this i got this errors

> Warning: move_uploaded_file(/AprimeWeb/img/face_merrick.jpg): failed
>   to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\UwAmp\www\AprimeWeb\admin\ajout-plaquette.php on line 44
>
> Warning: move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move
>   'C:\Users\theal\AppData\Local\Temp\php5F09.tmp' to
>   '/AprimeWeb/img/face_merrick.jpg' in
>   C:\UwAmp\www\AprimeWeb\admin\ajout-plaquette.php on line 44

My code :

```
require_once('connexion.php');

$return = array('success' => false);

$titre            = isset($_POST['titre']) ? $_POST['titre'] : null;
$lieu    = isset($_POST['lieu']) ? $_POST['lieu'] : null;
$annee    = isset($_POST['annee']) ? $_POST['annee'] : null;
$montant    = isset($_POST['montant']) ? $_POST['montant'] : null;
$prestation    = isset($_POST['prestation']) ? $_POST['prestation'] : null;
$detail    = isset($_POST['detail']) ? $_POST['detail'] : null;

//-----------------------

$fichier = basename($_FILES['image']['name']);


$extensions = array('.png', '.gif', '.jpg', '.jpeg');
$extension = strrchr($_FILES['image']['name'], '.');
$dossier = "/AprimeWeb/img/";
//-----------------------

if(!is_null($titre) && !is_null($lieu)  && !is_null($annee) && !is_null($montant) && !is_null($prestation) && !is_null($detail) && !is_null($fichier)) {

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO plaquettes SET titre = \'' . $titre . '\', lieu = \'' . $lieu . '\', annee = \'' . $annee . '\', montant = \'' . $montant . '\', prestation = \'' . $prestation . '\', detail = \'' . $detail . '\'';
    $return['success'] = $connexion->exec($sql);
}


if(!in_array($extension, $extensions))

{
     $erreurup = 'Vous devez uploader un fichier de type png, gif, jpg ou jpeg';
}

if(!isset($erreurup)) //S'il n'y a pas d'erreur, on upload
{

     $fichier = strtr($fichier,
          'ÀÁÂÃÄÅÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÒÓÔÕÖÙÚÛÜÝàáâãäåçèéêëìíîïðòóôõöùúûüýÿ',
          'AAAAAACEEEEIIIIOOOOOUUUUYaaaaaaceeeeiiiioooooouuuuyy');

     if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $dossier . $fichier))

    {
    $reqimg = $connexion->prepare('INSERT INTO plaquettes SET img = \'' . $fichier . '\'');
    $reqimg->execute(array($fichier));
    $reqimg->closeCursor();}
else
{    
    echo 'Echec de l\'upload !';
}
}else
{
     echo $erreurup;
}


echo json_encode($return);`
```

I dont know if its good to split my text add request and my picture add request but its more easier for me to check errors

Thanks for helping, if you can tell me how work a path in my $dossier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try with this path:
$dossier = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/AprimeWeb/img/';

Comment: That's works too i've got no errors but my $reqimg wont write anything in my image column in my database

Answer (score 1):

When you upload, you should use full path.

`$dossier = 'C:/UwAmp/www/AprimeWeb/img/';`

Also make sure `img` folder is writable.

Comment: Ah thats work better i have no errors, but i've nothing in my database for the column "image" :(